# How to request focus on currently expanded container layout inside nestedscrollview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus, nestedscrollview

I have following layout XML -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/checkout_activity_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".activities.CheckoutActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/marketplace_productvendor_page_back_button"
            android:onClick="backButtonPressed"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shopping_cart_framelayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_cart_imageView"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icons_32_x_32_black_shopping_cart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shopping_cart_counter"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@drawable/textview_round_background"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="16sp"
                app:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
                app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/activity_checkout_cart_imageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp"
                tools:text="1"
                tools:visibility="visible" />


        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_top_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_checkout_top_layout" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_checkout_top_view">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_checkout_stages_viewgroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_discount_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:text="@string/activity_checkout_checkout"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_first_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_first_stage_textview"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/color_black"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_billing_address_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_billing_address"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/billing_shipping__address_layout_bottom_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />


            <!-- Billing layout -->
            <include
                android:id="@+id/checkout_activity_billing_address_layout_include"
                layout="@layout/fragment_checkout_billing_shipping"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_billing_address_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_second_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_second_stage_textview"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_2"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_address_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_shipping_address"
                    android:textColor="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />

            <!-- Shipping layout -->
            <include
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_address_layout_include"
                layout="@layout/fragment_checkout_billing_shipping"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_address_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_third_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_third_stage_textview"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_3"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_method_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_shipping_method"
                    android:textColor="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_payment_method_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_shipping_method_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_forth_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_4"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_payment_method"
                    android:textColor="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_payment_information_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_fifth_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_fifth_stage"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_5"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_payment_information"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_payment_information"
                    android:textColor="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_confirm_order_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_payment_information_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_sixth_stage_viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_sixth_stage"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                    android:background="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout__6"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_confirm_information_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                    android:text="@string/activity_checkout_confirm_information"
                    android:textColor="@color/activity_checkout_unselected_checkout_stage_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_confirm_information_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marketplace_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marketplace_14dp"
                android:background="@color/activity_checkout_stages_line" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_checkout_confirm_information_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which looks like this visually -

Each FrameLayout is being inflated with a Fragment containing the content for each stage, meaning this is a long scrollable view - this why I use NestedScrollView.

The thing is that when I inflate the needed Fragment I will need to focus on that fragment also. How do I request focus and automatically scroll to it's position?

[image]

Comment: I didn't quite get you. Why have you created this anyway? `RecyclerView` is such an easier alternative.

Comment: I have 7 different layouts that needs to be scrolled down together, each one with different data types so I don't think RV would be the right structure to go.